# How to attach a file to a custom object from a visualforce page in lightning experience

Tags: visualforce, attachment, controller-extension

I need to attach a file to each record of a custom object from visualforce page in lightning experience.Here the i have tried so far but this fails to attch the file.

**VF Page:**

```
<apex:page standardController="Encounter__c" extensions="GetEncounterDetails_Controller" showHeader="true" lightningStylesheets="true">
<apex:slds />
<apex:form id="form">
    <apex:commandButton action="{!URLFOR($Action.Encounter__c.New)}" value="New Record" reRender="encounter"/>
    <apex:pageblock id="encounter">   
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Evercare Hospital of Austin " collapsible="true" >
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageblockTable value="{!customrecords}" var="e" >           
            <apex:column >               
                <apex:outputField value="{!e.Patient__c}"></apex:outputField><br></br>
                <apex:outputField value="{!e.Referring_Physician__c}"/><br></br>
                <apex:outputField value="{!e.Referring_Facility__c }"/><br></br>
            </apex:column>
           <apex:column >
               <apex:outputField value="{!e.User__c}" >
                   <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar_x-small">
                      <img src="/assets/images/avatar1.jpg" alt="meaningful text" />
                   </span>
               </apex:outputField>
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column >
                Attach <apex:inputFile id="fileToUpload" value="{!fileBody}" filename="{!fileName}" styleClass="input-file">
                       </apex:inputfile>
            <apex:actionRegion >
                <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!attach}" reRender="encounter">                   
                <apex:param name="{!e.id}" value="{!e.id}" assignTo="{!encounterId}"/> 
            </apex:commandButton>
            </apex:actionRegion>
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageblockTable>        
      </apex:pageblock>        
 </apex:form>
```

**Apex code:**

```
public class GetEncounterDetails_Controller {
    public List<Encounter__c> customrecords {get;set;}
    public String encounterId {get;set;}
    //public Attachment a {get;set;}
    public Attachment myAttachment{get;set;}
    public String fileName{get;set;}
    public Blob fileBody{get;set;}
    public GetEncounterDetails_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        customrecords = [select Name,User__c,Patient__c,Referring_Physician__c,Referring_Facility__c,Patient__r.Name,Patient__r.OwnerId from Encounter__c];
        //myAttachment = new Attachment();
        System.debug('****');
    }
    public PageReference attach() {       
        System.debug(encounterId);
        //myAttachment = new Attachment();
        System.debug('@@@@@fileBody'+fileBody);
        System.debug('@@@@@fileName'+fileName);
        PageReference pr;
        if(fileBody != null && fileName != null)  {           
            myAttachment = new Attachment();
            System.debug(myAttachment);
            System.debug('@@@@@fileBody'+fileBody);
            myAttachment.Body = fileBody;
            myAttachment.Name = fileName;
            myAttachment.ParentId = encounterId;            
            insert myAttachment;   
            pr= new PageReference('https://purohit-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/'+encounterId);
            pr.setRedirect(true);
            return pr;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here the encounterId is the particular record Id from list of encounter records and I am getting null value for file body and name in debug.Can any one please suggest where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Hope this suggestion isn't too far off base. I recently implemented some file upload features with Flows using recently available file upload component.
Users can enter some values in the flow (as needed) and drag-drop one or more files to attached to the flow's related record.

Comment: Thanks @debraSF for your response but I need that using VF page only &I have resolved this issue just by changing CommandButton to CommandLink.The problem here is when we use reRender attribute in CommandButton that returns Value of Param as null &removing this attribute throws error that REQUIRED FIELD MISSING.So I changed that to commandlink.Now my issue is I need to use SLDS class for choosefile button.When I use styleClass = "slds-file-selector__input slds-assistive-text" in <apex:inputFile> tag the button is not working.Do any one has solution for this.Please help me with this.URGENT!